# Why CustomTaskPane is throwing null exception

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm creating VSTO Add-in & i've tried [Add winform addin to Custom task pane in Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491946/add-winform-addin-to-custom-task-pane-in-word/19494373#19494373)
but it is throwing a NullReferenceException.

```
        CustomTaskPaneCollection CustomTaskPanes;
        CustomTaskPane ct;
        Pdfcontrol pdf = new Pdfcontrol();
        ct = Globals.ThisDocument.CustomTaskPanes.Add(pdf, "Pdf");
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @Chris please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ThisDocument` doesn't have a `CustomTaskPanes` property, this shouldn't even compile. The answer you got that from was for an application-level add-in, whereas you have a document-level add-in. In your case, you want to do this:

```
Pdfcontrol pdf = new Pdfcontrol();
Globals.ThisDocument.ActionsPane.Controls.Add(pdf)
```